# Regular expression in python to fetch a line that starts with one string, in middle some other string and ends with different string

Tags: python, python-re

**this is my code :**

```
 s="""
    [  8]   0.00-34.53  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  receiver    
    [SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   624 Mbits/sec                  sender    
    [ 12]   0.00-34.53  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  receive
    [SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
    [SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   824 Mbits/sec                  sender
    [SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
    """
   items=re.findall("^.[SUM].*sender",s,re.MULTILINE)
     for x in items:
     print(x)
```

which gives the output :

```
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   624 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   824 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.75  sec  0.00 Bytes  0.00 bits/sec                  sender
```

but i want to get the below output, that starts with string [SUM] and ends with string sender and should not display the line that has any 0.00 bytes and 0.00 bits/sec

```
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   624 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   824 Mbits/sec                  sender
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you - you might want to make some tweaking for your specific needs:

```
In [151]: regex = "^(\[SUM\](?!.*(([0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}).*){3}.*0\.00).*sender)"

In [152]: items=re.findall(regex,s,re.MULTILINE)
     ...: for x in items:
     ...:     print(x)
     ...:     
('[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   624 Mbits/sec                  sender', '', '')
('[SUM]   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11 GBytes   824 Mbits/sec                  sender', '   0.00', '   0.00-34.53  sec  2.11')
```

Answer (score 0):

With negative lookahead, you could use this regex:

```
reg = "^\s*\[SUM\]\s*[0-9\-\.]+\s+sec(?!\s+0\.00 Bytes).*sender.*"
items=re.findall(reg,s,re.MULTILINE)
for line in items:
    print(line)
```

The ?! indicates that the regex after should not be a match. [More info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)